# style-loader injects css dynamically

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

Is there a specific reason why webpack's style-loader injects css into html dynamically? I mean, the generated html doesn't contain the <style> tag when I view it in my text editor, but loading the same page in browser I can see that it is actually there. And is there a way to make it a part of html generation process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack bundles all resources together including CSS and injects it on the fly, producing no static CSS in HTML at build-time. For development you have no reason to change this. For production, you can have Webpack extract CSS into separate files by using [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/)